# SUM in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

how can I have the sum of column Delay?

```
$lists_Drier = DB::connection('Plc')
                ->select("SELECT TOP $Count_Row * 
                            FROM tbl_StatusLog 
                            WHERE Line = $line 
                            AND Type = 'Drier' 
                            AND Status = 1 
                            AND Delay >= $Delay1 
                            AND Delay <= $Delay2 
                            AND TimeStamp >= $Tarikh1 
                            AND TimeStamp <= $Tarikh2 
                          ORDER BY Id DESC");
```

Comment: I assume you are using SQLServer as your database?

Comment: Do you want the sum of the whole table, or the sum of the `TOP $Count_Row` selection?

Comment: The database is SQL Server, I want the sum of the Delay column in the table